# How to get lines from a file and parse them

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm not sure how to save the lines in such a way that: `Element bb_lst[0]` should be a list with the column headings: `[“Season”, ”Age”, ”Tm”, ……., “PTS”]`.

Heres the assignment:

> a) **Write a function called get_csv_data() that takes these
>   parameters:**
>
> • **f**: an open file object in CSV format (similar to our
>   lb-james.csv file), where the first line has only column headings,
>   followed by lines with comma-separated data items,
>
> • **string_pos_lst**: a list with index positions (starting from 0)
>   for columns that have a string format. For the lb-james.csv file, this
>   list should be [0, 2, 3, 4]. All other columns are assumed to have a
>   float format. Assume that this list is not sorted in any way.
>
> • **sep**: a string representing the column separator with default
>   value “,” The function get_csv_data returns a nested list we call here
>   data_lst, as follows:
>
> • it reads the first line from file f (with the column headings) and
>   adds to data_lst a list with the column heading strings,
>
> • after that first line, it reads file f line by line and parses each
>   line based on the string_pos_lst parameter. All columns on a line are
>   assumed to be floats if not specifically indicated in the
>   string_pos_lst list. The function adds the list with parsed tokens
>   (floats or/and strings) to the data_lst list. Lines with at least one
>   parsing error are ignored. E.g. trying to call float(‘’) will raise
>   ValueError; we skip this entire line and go to the next one.
>
> **Error handling**: check parameters for invalid values (e.g. sep==empty string). It is acceptable for this function to throw/raise
>   `IndexError and errors related to I/O failures.
>
> Example. Here is how this function can be used:
>
> ```
> bb_file = open(“lb-james.csv”, “r”)
>
> bb_lst = get_csv_data(bb_file, [0, 2, 3, 4], “,”)
> ```
>
> (error handling is omitted here for brevity)
>
> Element `bb_lst[0]` should be a list with the column headings:
>
> ```
> [“Season”,”Age”,”Tm”, ……., “PTS”]
> ```
>
> Element `bb_lst[1]` should be a list with column
>
> ```
> for line 1 data:
>  [“2003-04”,19.0,”CLE”,”NBA”,”SG”,79.0,79.0, …….., 1.9,20.9].
> ```
>
> Notice the types of the elements: they are strings for column indices
>   given in list [0, 2, 3, 4] or floats otherwise.

**Here's my code:**

```
def get_csv_data(f,string_pos_lst,sep):
    for line in f:
        content = [line.strip(sep) for x, line in enumerate(f)]

    for x in range(len(string_pos_lst)):
        print(content[string_pos_lst[x]])

#Test
f = open("lb-james.csv","r")
string_pos_lst = [0,2,3,4]
sep=","
bb_file = open("lb-james.csv", "r")
bb_lst = get_csv_data(bb_file, [0, 2, 3, 4], ",")
```

Output:

```
2003-04,19,CLE,NBA,SG,79,79,39.5,7.9,18.9,.417,0.8,2.7,.290,7.1,16.1,.438,.438,4.4,5.8,.754,1.3,4.2,5.5,5.9,1.6,0.7,3.5,1.9,20.9
2005-06,21,CLE,NBA,SF,79,79,42.5,11.1,23.1,.480,1.6,4.8,.335,9.5,18.3,.518,.515,7.6,10.3,.738,0.9,6.1,7.0,6.6,1.6,0.8,3.3,2.3,31.4
2006-07,22,CLE,NBA,SF,78,78,40.9,9.9,20.8,.476,1.3,4.0,.319,8.6,16.8,.513,.507,6.3,9.0,.698,1.1,5.7,6.7,6.0,1.6,0.7,3.2,2.2,27.3
```

How do I parse the lines? All I want to do is essentially read the file line by line. Thanks!

Comment: Use `.split(sep)` not `.strip(sep)`.

Comment: What are you supposed to do with the headers? I couldn't understand that part

Comment: Im not sure, my professors english isnt good at times. i believe he wanted us to make the headers all strings and everything else match the data types